# How to use Autocomplete with jqGrid library Lib.Web.MVC

Tags: jqgrid, lib.web.mvc

I need an example to help me implement Autocomplete with jqGrid library Lib.Web.MVC.

The functionality is announced in this [blog](http://tpeczek.blogspot.com/2011/07/jqgrid-strongly-typed-helper-caption.html). A nice screenshot is provided but no sample code for these two:

- `JqGridColumnEditTypes.JQueryUIAutocomplete`
- `JqGridColumnSearchTypes.JQueryUIAutocomplete`

This code gives an error `object referenced not found`:

```
[Required]
[JqGridColumnSortable(true)]
[JqGridColumnSearchable(true, SearchType=JqGridColumnSearchTypes.JQueryUIAutocomplete)]
public string Place { set; get; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned blog post contains link to [sample project](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/62741).

In order for `JqGridColumnSearchTypes.JQueryUIAutocomplete` to work you need to provide controller and action name as parameters for the attribute, something like this:

```
[Required]
[JqGridColumnSortable(true)]
[JqGridColumnSearchable(true, "ActionName", "ControllerName", SearchType=JqGridColumnSearchTypes.JQueryUIAutocomplete)]
public string Place { set; get; }
```

The action needs to return data in jQuery UI autocomplete compatible format, so something like this:

```
public ActionResult Places(string term)
{
    return Json(
        _placesRepository
            .Find(String.Format("Name.StartsWith(\"{0}\")", term))
            .Select(p => p.Name).ToArray()
        , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @BarryMSIH: You should not forget to vote all helpful answer. It helps other users to find helpful information on the stackoverflow. You have right to vote 30 answers or questions **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213)), but you voted up in 1.5 year less then your days limit. Please be not so economical and use your voting right more if you want to help other visitors.